# Equivalent definition of locally integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

If we know that $\int_{U} f\cdot \phi<\infty$ for all test functions $\phi\in C_c^\infty(U)$ where $U\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is some open set, can we conclude that $\int_U |f\cdot \phi|<\infty$ for all test functions as well?

Comment: What do you mean by $\int_{U} f\cdot \phi<\infty$? The key point is here.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I consider this $\int_U f\cdot \phi<\infty$ as the Lebesgue integral of the measurable function $f\cdot \phi$ over the open set $U$, where $\phi\in C_c^\infty(U)$, and I want to conclude that $f\in L_{loc}^1(U)$.

Comment: In this case, a function $h$ is integrable if $\int\left\lvert  h\right\rvert<+\infty$ so if you apply this to $h=f\cdot\phi$ you get what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, but where does the condition $\int |h|<\infty$ come from? Actually what I'm thinking is that what if we allow cancellation in this case, can we use $\phi$ to detect the cancellation? it's easy to see that if $f\ge 0$, then $\int_U f\cdot \phi<\infty$ implies $\int_U |f\cdot \phi|<\infty$, but if $f=f^+-f^-$, then I'm not sure if this is still true. Please let me know if there's anything here that could cause misunderstanding. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I see your point, I shouldn't have said that it's Lebesgue integral!